# How to run a Github Action's step based on output condition?

Tags: python, github-actions, flake8

I would like to comment on a PR if there are more than 100 flake8 errors but it's not going to disable the merge button.

My approach is something like this:

```
name: Flake8 Check
on:  [pull_request]

jobs:
  flake8:
    name: Flake8 Check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.6

      - name: Install dependency
        run: pip install flake8

      - name: Flake8
        id: flake
        run: echo "::set-output name=number::$(flake8 --config=tools/dev/.flake8 --count -qq)"


      - name: comment PR
        uses: unsplash/comment-on-pr@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          msg: "There are ${{ steps.flake.outputs.number }} Flake8 errors which is a lot :disappointed: \nThis will not block you to merge it but please try to fix them."
          check_for_duplicate_msg: true
        if: ${{ steps.flake.outputs.number }} > 100
```

However, it is commenting even though there is less than 100 errors. I've check the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#operators) and it looks correct to me.

What is that I am missing?

Comment: Alternatively you may put the `> 100` inside the double curly braces where you have full boolean evaluation with `&&`, `||` and parenthesis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the github actions page for [contexts](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#about-contexts-and-expressions), they recommend not using `${{ }}` in the condition of the `if` context, although they also [show](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-expression-in-an-if-conditional) an `if` condition that uses the `${{ }}` syntax, but I guess it does not actually work as you have shown here.

So in your case, you need to change your `if` to:

```
if: steps.flake.outputs.number > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

if: ${{ steps.flake.outputs.number }} > 100

The documentation seems to show that using the ${{ }} turns the contents into a string, which won't be helping your comparison.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).