# In a GitHub Action how to conditionalize a step based off the previous step's output?

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

Building a GitHub action based on the commit message I'm trying to base a step on whether the commit message contains a particular string, set it to a variable and then in the next step check with a condition.

My current implementation of my action works:

```
name: Smoke Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  contents: read
  issues: write

jobs:
  smoking:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Run smoke tests
        if: ${{ !contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'smoke_test') }}
        run: |
          echo 'Smoke Test not requested'
          exit 1
  stuff:
    needs: smoking
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: JasonEtco/create-an-issue@v2
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        with:
          filename: .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/smoke-test.md
        id: create-issue
      - run: 'echo Created issue number ${{ steps.create-issue.outputs.number }}'
      - run: 'echo Created ${{ steps.create-issue.outputs.url }}'
```

but with the implementation of:

```
exit 1
```

causes the action to indicate it error'ed out in the action panel and while that works that isn't technically accurate because I don't need it to error I just don't want the remaining steps to run.

I've tried setting a variable:

```
if: ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'smoke_test') }}
with:
  run-smoke-test: true
run: |
  echo 'Smoke Test requested'
```

but it's not passing to the next step.

### Research

- [Use environment variable in github action if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882715/use-environment-variable-in-github-action-if)
- [How to pass variable between two successive GitHub Actions jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738070/how-to-pass-variable-between-two-successive-github-actions-jobs)
- [github-action: does the IF have an ELSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916931/github-action-does-the-if-have-an-else)
- [How to fail a job in GitHub Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903836/how-to-fail-a-job-in-github-actions)
- [GitHub Actions - trigger another action after one action is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750603/github-actions-trigger-another-action-after-one-action-is-completed)

Without relying on another GitHub action is there a way in step `smoking` to set an env variable that step `stuff` would need to validate for before running the step?

### Edit

After reading the [answer](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs) and implementing [job outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs) I've written:

```
name: Smoke Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  contents: read
  issues: write

jobs:
  commitMessage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.isSmoke.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: isSmoke
        if: ${{ contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'smoke_test') }}
        run: echo "::set-output name=test::true"

  smokeTest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: commitMessage
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: JasonEtco/create-an-issue@v2
        if: steps.isSmoke.output.test == true
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEV_TOKEN }}
        with:
          filename: .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/smoke-test.md
```

but when the commit message of `smoke_test` is used it bypasses `create-an-issue`:

[image]

and I'm basing my condition after reading "[Run github actions step based on output condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801096/run-github-actions-step-based-on-output-condition)" and reading:

- [Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#about-contexts-and-expressions)
- [Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions)
- [Using conditions to control job execution](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution)

Can a condition come before a step and/or what is the correct way to run a step based off the previous step?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [job outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs), which allow you to send data to the following jobs.